# How to add a new service behavior to an existing WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I want to add a new method to an existing WCF service so I added the new method and its contract as follows.

My contract class

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService
{
    //Existing Contract
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResult MyServiceMethod1(String input);


    //Existing Contract
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResult MyServiceMethod2(String input);

    //New Contract
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResult NewServiceMethod(String input);
}
```

My service class

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    //Existing Method
    [OperationBehavior]
    public ServiceResult MyServiceMethod1(String input)
    {
        // some operation
    }

    //Existing Method
    [OperationBehavior]
    public ServiceResult MyServiceMethod2(String input)
    {
         // some operation
    }

    //Added new method
    [OperationBehavior]
    public ServiceResult NewServiceMethod(String input)
    {
         // some operation
    }
}
```

Once  I added the new behavior I compiled the project which succeeded without errors. Then I went to my web app and updated my service references but I got the following error. 
[image]

I am not exactly sure what I'm missing here. When I remove the newly added function and update the service it works without any problems. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the current service reference and adding it fresh?

Comment: 404 doesn't sound like it's related to your change. The error message states that the "metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved". Check that URL and find out why it's not there.

Comment: @Tim I tried deleting and referencing the service again. I still get the same metadata error but when remove the newly added methods it works properly.